# Need help understanding the shell help options

Tags: shell, documentation, dos, filehelpers

I face very often the problem to understand a syntax of Shell commads help which i usually get using options `--h or -h or /?` etc. when there are more than 2 or 3 options.

What does this form called? any help docs or links which explain the help syntax are welcome.

whats the difference between `[ options ]` and `{ options }` what does the `*` or the `|` mean and how do i use it? how important is the order of the options usually? please provide me some good links to documentation about this.

Comment: It would be useful to know about which specific shell you are talking. Windows cmdline? PowerShell? A Linux shell such as BASH, tcsh, ...?

Comment: Edit your message and copy/paste 1 or 2 of the help messages that are confusing you and it will be easier for people to comment and provide help. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commands given to a CLI (Command line interface) shell are often in one of the following forms:

- [doSomething] [how] [toFiles]
- [doSomething] [how] [sourceFile] [destinationFile]
- [doSomething] [how] < [inputFile] > [outputFile]
- [doSomething] [how] | [doSomething] [how] | [do Something] [how] > [outputFile]

this was taken from [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_Line_Interface) guess it doesnt answer exactly the question but its very relevant, take a look at the "Anatomy of a shell CLI"-section.

[Here](http://www.easydos.com/dosindex.html) you can find a good documented help with examples for each command.